# How do i run javascript in a eval function

Tags: javascript, html, html-helper

Hi im trying to run js code in a eval() function specifically im trying to disable extentions when you run index.html this is what is inside index.html:

index.html:

```js
<script>
  var newWin = window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstorex");
  newWin.fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myuser/myrep/myfile.js").then(data=>  {data.text().then(text=>{eval(text)})})
</script>
```

myfile.js:

```js
const extensions =['icmgjiknkpcfkhgajgmpkkehdjmidlgl','adkcpkpghahmbopkjchobieckeoaoeem','cgbbbjmgdpnifijconhamggjehlamcif','kkbmdgjggcdajckdlbngdjonpchpaiea','dmdmgaepfoakhbmfckjjfilpgmceocgl']
let disabled = 0
for( e in extensions ){
  chrome.management.setEnabled(extensions[e], false, ()=>{disabled  })
}
alert("disabled extensions");
```

the reason i am trying to run this in a eval function is because fetch does not work because for some reason it executes inside of the source page and not the new link but eval does so i was wondering if anyone had a work around or could make this code into a eval function?

Comment: I think you need `newWin.eval(...)` to execute the code in the new window.

Comment: i know but i cant do newWin.eval(const extensions =['icmgjiknkpcfkhgajgmpkkehdjmidlgl','adkcpkpghahmbopkjchobieckeoaoeem','cgbbbjmgdpnifijconhamggjehlamcif','kkbmdgjggcdajckdlbngdjonpchpaiea','dmdmgaepfoakhbmfckjjfilpgmceocgl']
let disabled = 0
for( e in extensions ){
  chrome.management.setEnabled(extensions[e], false, ()=>{disabled  })
}
alert("disabled extensions");)

Comment: I mean `.then(text=>{newWin.eval(text)})})`

Comment: text=fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillipbruh/snowplus/main/idk')
.then(function (response) {response.text().then(function (text) {eval(text);}); });

window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstorex").then(text=>{newWin.eval(text)})})


does not work

Comment: `window.open()` doesn't return a Promise, it returns the new window object, so you can't use `.then()`

Comment: so how can i inject it?

Comment: But really, never use `eval`. And certainly not for this use-case: extensions are controlled by the user's browser, your website does not get to turn them on or off.

Comment: Code does not make sense since you are trying to run extension code... That is not going to run in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
  var newWin = window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstorex");
  newWin.fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myuser/myrep/myfile.js").then(data=>  {data.text().then(text=>{eval(text)})})
</script>
```